# Cumulative distribution function in powerlaw distribution

Tags: distributions, maximum-likelihood, fitting, continuous-data, power-law

I am trying to fit the power law distribution to continuous sample (x) which has a sample size n = 360

I'm using the methodology proposed by Aaron Clauset in the python package

power-law: A Python Package for Analysis of Heavy-Tailed Distributions

My steps for power-law distribution are as follows:

1. I fix the lower bound (xmin) by myself and estimate the parameter α of the power-law model using ML by applying powerlaw.Fit function. I get α= 2.11 at xmin = 1.89

`` fit = powerlaw.Fit(x,discrete=False,xmin=`1.89, xmax=None,verbose=False, fit_method='Likelihood',estimate_discrete=False,discrete_approximation='round',sigma_threshold=None,parameter_range=None,fit_optimizer=None,xmin_distance='D',xmin_distribution='power_law') ``

2. I use the fit.plot_ccdf function to plot the Cumulative distribution function (CCDF).

`ax1 = fit.plot_ccdf(original_data=False,survival=True,linewidth = 3,linestyle = '--',label = 'Obs' ) fit.power_law.plot_ccdf(ax = ax1, color = 'r', linestyle = '--', label = 'powerlaw')`.

According to the theory mentioned in Aaron Clauset (2009), it seems I can calculate cumulative distribution only for those values where (x> xmin). As you can see in the figure below, here: I plot the ccdf function for values above the xmin.It works perfectly for the values above the threshold (i.e xmin) as shown below.

[image]

I want to calculate the cdf also for the values where x < xmin (i.e., for whole distribution).When I use the method proposed by Aaron Clauset (2009) to calculate the exceedance for whole sample. It changes the probability of also large values as shown in Figure 2.

[image]

3. I tried modifying the equation as ccdf =1- (x)^(1-α) to calculate the CCDF for the whole sample instead of using build in function function ccdf = 1-(x/xmin)^(1-α)  but do not get desired results.
   I would appreciate any help regarding this issue. Thanks

Comment: The CCDF where $x\le x_{min}$ equals $1,$ by definition.  This casts doubt on what you are trying to do.  Could you explain?

Comment: Hi, @whuber thank you for your reply. I tried to clarify my question in the post. Yes, I understand  CCDF where x≤xmin should be equal to 1. But in the package, it seems not working. So I m just wondering if we can not get values of CCDF when x < xmin in case of power law distribution?

Comment: To rephrase @whuber's comment - how can $x$ be less than $x_{min}$?   $x_{min}$ is supposed to be the lower bound on $x$; if you have $x < x_{min}$, your value for $x_{min}$ is obviously wrong, impossibly so, and it seems to me that all your problems flow from that.

Comment: I still cannot make any sense of this question.  Perhaps I have a different understanding of what you might mean by "xmin."  I understand it to be the minimum of the support of the distribution, which is equivalent to saying the CCDF equals $1$ for all lesser values of its argument.

Comment: Thank you @jbowman for your input.  yes, you are right xmin is lower bound in this case.  I am trying to apply the method of left censoring  (i.e., fitting of the distribution above a threshold, in my case this threshold is  xmin) and plotting the CCDF for whole sample. What I do expect is probability should be the same for the x > xmin as in figure  1. But probability for the x < xmin should not be greater than 1.

Comment: Setting $x_{min}$ at the censoring point is not the way to handle left-censoring... if how to handle left censoring is the issue, I'd suggest rewriting the question to reflect that.